# Tensorflow-GPU is super slow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Python (3.5) with tensorflow-gpu now quite a bit. My tasks are developing neural networks (CNN) for the processing of images. I made some evaluations for different networks with about 90,000 images. The normal runtime for one epoch in the network I am using is 60s, but today something changed and now I have no real calculation power because my network needs about 400s to calculate 1 epoch.

So far I checked and did the following:

- I checked my tensorflow-gpu library which is 1.3.0rc0
- I installed the CUDA 8.0 and the CUDNN 6.1 again
- I checked if tensorflow is recognizing my GPU as the preferred calculation device (works)
- I checked my code again and nothing has changed in it

So I think with the installation of some new drivers/Windows 10 updates something in my environment changed. What makes me suspicious is that when I start my python program the memory that I am allocating is 34 GB (which exceeds my RAM; I have 16 Gb). In addition, the SSD access is really poor, but I checked if the SSD had a failure and everything seems right.

So now I have no idea why my system has no calculation power anymore. There must be a bottleneck but I have no idea where to check. Can someone give me some tips?